# Win10: Can I have an admin password for installs and changes, but not have to go through a login screen (ever)?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

As it says in the title I would like for windows to always (even better if this can be disabled for a specific duration) ask for a password on installs and system changes, but not for login after wake up or power on. I know how to disable wake-up logins, but not how to get to happen and still require a password on installs and changes.

Comment: "I know how to disable wake-up logins, but not how to get to happen and still require a password on installs and changes." - Make your user profile a member of the local Users user group, and remove the permissions to install programs, this will require you to provide the credentials for a second account.  How you remove the ability for a user to install programs is well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a standard user account separate from your admin account and always use the standard account, it should prompt for administrator credentials for any system changes (including installs). Then you can set the computer to automatically log in to the standard user account on startup.